# Query to return the data from single table, two columns with same value

Tags: postgresql

[image]

I have a table like above.

My requirement is to write a query where I will pass the id value in the where clause and same value could be a parent_id also so I should get two records.

Ex: If I pass the id value as 1 then I will get two record because 1 is id value at the same time its child value is 2 (parent_id=1).

like wise I need an hierarchy.

could you please help with the query.

Please note I need the hierarchy not just like

where id=? as parent id=?   (here ? value is same in both conditions)

Comment: Share what you have tried so far. Add the produced output and mention the desired output so that people can understand the requirement better.

Comment: do you expect to have also "grand-parent" (or higher) in your hierarchy? for example id -> parent -> grand-parent...
if so, you might need to use CTE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `or` is enough for your use case

```sql
select *
from tab
where id = 1 or parent_id = 1;
```

Output:

```
 id | organization_id |  name  | parent_id 
----+-----------------+--------+-----------
  1 |               2 | suresh |         0
  2 |               2 | naresh |         1
```

Comment: i need hierarchy Umut, i hope you understand what i mean that.

Comment: Can you eloborate on what you want with an example table output.